# Terminal's "codesign" command trouble

Tags: macos, terminal, info.plist, codesign

I've been trying to use the "codesign" command on Mail.app so that I can modify the info.plist using the "defaults write" command. It used to work, but after I re-installed Yosemite, I get this result when running the command:

```
/Applications/Mail.app: no identity found
```

I ran this command:

```
codesign -f -s /Applications/Mail.app
```

If anyone could tell me how I could properly run the codesign command on Mail.app so that I can modify the info.plist of Mail.app using the "defaults write" command, that would be nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're just missing a parameter here.  I can re-codesign an app using --force and specifying exactly which signature I want to use:

```
$ codesign --force -s "Developer ID Application: Michael Dautermann" Mail.app
Mail.app: replacing existing signature
```

And if you want to verify that Mail.app is indeed signed, here is what my copy of Mail looks like before I forced my signature onto it:

```
$codesign --display --verbose=4 Mail.app
Executable=/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
Identifier=com.apple.mail
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=23743 flags=0x0(none) hashes=1179+5 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=a3920218afa4f082aac98bf486dd797b13fde588
Signature size=4097
Authority=Software Signing
Authority=Apple Code Signing Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Info.plist entries=41
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=15 files=262
Internal requirements count=1 size=64
```

Comment: For the "Developer ID Application: Michael Dautermann" part, do I need to register somewhere to get an account, or is it something involving keychain access? No matter what I put, I keep getting the message

    Developer ID Application: (my name): no identity found

Comment: The easiest way to get your certificate is to pay Apple to enroll in the MacOS Developer program (it's $99 here in the US and something roughly similar wherever you are in the world).  If you want to use your own certificate, that's probably an option too.  There's more detail in the "OSX Code Signing In Depth" document (and [here I'm linking to the "creating a self-signed code signing certificate using OpenSSL section](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG10)).

Comment: Hi, I found a code that works (or at least seems to work) without a signature:

codesign -f -s - /Applications/Mail.app

I have to use sudo for it to work. Sudo defaults write also works after running that code on the Info.plist for mail (or at least, again, seems to work). However when I open Mail.app, it just automatically closes again. I suspect that this is due to the fact that Mail tracked an unauthorized change in code.

More specifically, my commands are:

'sudo codesign -f -s - /Applications/Mail.app', and 
'sudo defaults write /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/Info LSUIElement 1'